# How Can I Turn my Line Plot into a Histogram?

Tags: python, plot, histogram

I am very new to Python and I am trying to create a histogram comparing temperatures collected by 4 sensors in a single day. I have already binned my data and am able to create a line graph, but I'm having a lot of trouble making the equivalent histogram.

My code is below and each "jun20BHX" below is an ndarray I made by taking average temperatures hour by hour from some CSVs I have with all the temp data.

````
plt.plot(jun20BH1[:,1],jun20BH1[:,2], label = 'Full Shade', linewidth = 4, linestyle='solid')
plt.plot(jun20BH2[:,1],jun20BH2[:,2], label = 'Full Sun',linewidth = 4)
plt.plot(jun20BH3[:,1],jun20BH3[:,2], label = 'Partial Sun #1', linewidth = 4)
plt.plot(jun20BH4[:,1],jun20BH4[:,2], label = 'Partial Sun #2', linewidth = 4)

plt.xlabel("Hour of Day", fontsize = 24)
plt.ylabel("Temperature (F)", fontsize = 24)
plt.xticks(fontsize = 20)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 20)
plt.legend(fontsize = 20)
plt.title("June 20 Boerum Hill", fontsize = 50)

plt.show()```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!
````

Answer (score 0):

You can try hist in numpy like this:

```
ax.hist(data,bins=100,range=(minimum,maximum),facecolor="r", histtype = 'step')
```

check this [numpy plot and hist](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_histogram_using_matplotlib.htm) for more details.